# vimscript parse yaml header and output to mapping

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, regular-expression, vimgrep

My goal is to make a mapping, that depending on the value of `type` in the yaml header, will run a command sourcing a file named the same as the value of `type`.

I have file containing a yaml header like

```
---
opt1: test
opt2: something else
type: mytemplate
---
```

and I've made a mapping

```
nnoremap <leader>mp :w!<cr>:exe "!command --template=/home/.../{}.ext -o " . fnameescape(expand('%:p:r')) . ".ext " . fnameescape(expand('%:p'))<cr>
```

and the characters `{}` should be replaced with the value of `type`
I have succeeded in making a bashcript, that will get the value like this

```
TYPE=$(egrep 'type:' filename.ext | awk -F 'type: ' '{print $2}')
command --template=/home/.../$TYPE.ext $@
```

But I'd like to do it purely in vim. I've tried using vim-grep, and got

```
:vimgrep 'type: ' % | %s=^\(type:\s\)\zs.*=
```

but this is a substitution, and can't be used in the mapping.
Any help would be gratefully appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a function to do so?

```
function! SourceByType()
    " save position
    let savePosition = getpos('.')

    " Get the line containing the type
    normal! gg
    let line = search('^type: .*\n---', 'W') 

    " no type found: abort
    if (line == 0)
        echo "no type found"
        return 1
    endif

    " Get the type
    let type = matchlist(getline(line), 'type: \(.*\)')[1]

    " Execute the commands
    execute ':w!'
    execute '!command --template=/home/.../'. type . '.ext -o ' . fnameescape(expand('%:p:r')) . '.ext ' . fnameescape(expand('%:p'))

    " restore position
    call setpos('.', savePosition)
endfunction
```

And a mapping calling the function:

```
nnoremap <leader>mp :call SourceByType()<CR>
```

What the function does:

- Saves the position of the cursor
- Goes to the top of the file
- Searches for a line containing `type: something` followed by a line containing `---`
- If no line was found, stop the execution
- Matches the `something` in `type: something`
- Executes your commands replacing `{}` by the type found.

Comment: This works great, but what does the line `let line = search('^type: .*\n---', 'W')` do?

Comment: See [`:h search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29): I get the number of the line matching the pattern `^type: .*\n---` which means a line containing `type: ` followed by any number of characters `.*` followed by a new line `\n` containing `---`. This allows me to then get the content of the line and match the type with `let type = matchlist(getline(line), 'type: \(.*\)')[1]` (I had to edit this line because of a typo.

Comment: Could `\n---` be substituted for $, so `type:` doesn't have to be the final yaml option?

Comment: @martinmch Absolutely it should work properly.